# log4j.properties does not switch off output

Tags: java, log4j

I have a Java project `ami` which has a dependency on my package `pdf2svg` which has a dependency on Apache's `PDFBox 1.8.7`. `PDFBox` is outputting copious debug information from (e.g. `org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont`) which I want to switch off.

```
732 [main] DEBUG org.xmlcml.pdf2svg.PDFPage2SVGConverter  - startStream
2243 [main] DEBUG org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont  - Debug: 'WinAnsiEncoding' isn't a predefined map, most likely it's embedded in the pdf itself.
2246 [main] DEBUG org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont  - Debug: 'WinAnsiEncoding' isn't a predefined map, most likely it's embedded in the pdf itself.
```

PDFBox cannot be edited and I want to switch off the DEBUG. 
I have `src/main/resources/log4j.properties` files in both `pdf2svg` and `ami` which currently contain the following

```
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.
#

log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, A1
log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.A1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
log4j.logger.uk.ac.cam=DEBUG

log4j.logger.org.xmlcml.cml.converters.molecule.cml.CML2CMLConverter=ALL
log4j.logger.org.apache.pdfbox.util=INFO
log4j.logger.org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine=INFO
log4j.logger.org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFObjectStreamParser=INFO
log4j.logger.org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSDocument=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.xobject.PDPixelMap=INFO
log4j.logger.org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.color.PDSeparation=OFF
log4j.logger.org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.color.PDColorState=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.color.PDICCBased=INFO
```

some of the commands seem to work, but others like

`log4j.logger.org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont=ERROR`

do not switch off output. Does it matter where I put the log4j.properties file?  Is there an obvious answer to the problem?

Comment: The first step in troubleshooting this would be to confirm that the log4j.properties file is being read by the log4j library at runtime. May be the file you are modifying is not the file that the library is reading.

Comment: Very possibly. How do I debug this?

Comment: One way would be remove all the loggers and add just one simple logger that logs everything and a file appender. The existence of the log file will confirm the log4j.properties be read at runtime.

Comment: the problem is that the DEBUG comes from PDFBox.jar which I can't edit

Comment: You don't have to edit PDFBOX. You have to edit the above mentioned log4j.properties and confirm that this is the properties file that is read at runtime.

Comment: I have 3 linked JAR files each with a log4j.properties. How do I find out which is which? If you can answer this I will accept the answer

Comment: Try this - Use the 
-Dlog4j.configuration=file:/full_path/log4j.properties jvm argument to make the log4j library read the properties file that you want. Change the logging levels to the desired ones in this file and let me know if it works.

Comment: As it seems to me you can add breakpoints on http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/logging/log4j/trunk/src/main/java/org/apache/log4j/helpers/Loader.java?view=markup class. That is used by http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/logging/log4j/trunk/src/main/java/org/apache/log4j/LogManager.java?view=markup to look up the log4j.properties. Then you can figure out which property file is loaded. Debugging always work.